# Ruby: Ice cream with decorators

Tags: ruby

I am writing a simple program that calculates the cost of ice cream.

The process is pretty simple: pick a cone, pick some flavors, pick some toppings, then pay the amount.

There are a bunch of different cones, and a bunch of different flavors, and a bunch of different toppings.

My design is to use decorator classes to wrap the ice cream similar to how you would place an order.

So I have my base Ice Cream class that provides an "amount" attribute indicating how much the thing costs, along with decorator classes for the Cone, Flavor, and Toppings. Each class will take an ice cream object and add to the amount, so you basically mix and match different types of ice creams.

I have another class that handles the actual money transaction, which takes various objects and calculates the price. In particular, if it sees an Ice Cream, it will perform some ice cream related processes.

Now, this design sounds fine and all, but how do I check whether the object that comes out of the ice cream maker is an ice cream type? After all, it will in theory be wrapped around with a bunch of decorators, so if you ask for its class you'll probably see something like Topping  rather than just ice cream. Ice Cream isn't necessary the super class either; it might be several classes up in the hierarchy.

`<topping ice cream>.Instanceof(Ice_Cream)` doesn't seem to work.

Also, I've implemented it using a set of classes. Are there other ways in ruby that I can use to achieve this type of design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should show us some code, but Ruby has `Object#is_a?` and `Class#===` that can be helpful here:

```
class MyString < String ; end
MyString.new.is_a? String #=> true
String === MyString.new #=> true
class AnotherString < MyString ; end
AnotherString.new.is_a? String #=> true
String === AnotherString.new #=> true
```

If you wonder about `Class#===`, it's mostly for use in case statements:

```
case value
when String
  # something
when Array
  # something else
end
```

For more idiomatic design approaches, you probably should look into modules and their use as mixins:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html